# mkfs.erofs erofs: failed to lookup selabel

Tags: android, image, filesystems

I am trying to convert a Ex4 android img to erofs, and thus need to keep selinux contexts.

I am using this command sudo ../mkfs.erofs -z lz4 -C 65536 --fs-config-file $config `--file-contexts $contexts  ../system.erofs .`

However for every file, I am getting this error

```
<E> erofs: failed to lookup selabel for /mnt/mydisk/mounted-system-erofs/system/apex/com.google.android.cellbroadcast_compressed.apex: [Error 0] Success
```

This is a snipet from $contexts.

```
\|d\|e\|b\|u\|g\|_\|r\|a\|m\|d\|i\|s\|k\| u:object_r:tmpfs:s0
\|d\|e\|v\| u:object_r:device:s0
\|d\|p\|o\|l\|i\|c\|y\|_\|s\|y\|s\|t\|e\|m\| u:object_r:rootfs:s0
\|e\|f\|s\| u:object_r:efs_file:s0
\|e\|t\|c\| u:object_r:rootfs:s0
\|i\|n\|i\|t\| u:object_r:init_exec:s0
\|i\|n\|i\|t\|\\|.\|c\|o\|n\|t\|a\|i\|n\|e\|r\|\\|.\|r\|c\| u:object_r:rootfs:s0
\|i\|n\|i\|t\|\\|.\|e\|n\|v\|i\|r\|o\|n\|\\|.\|r\|c\| u:object_r:rootfs:s0
\|k\|e\|y\|r\|e\|f\|u\|g\|e\| u:object_r:keyrefuge_data_file:s0
\|l\|i\|n\|k\|e\|r\|c\|o\|n\|f\|i\|g\| u:object_r:linkerconfig_file:s0
\|l\|o\|s\|t\|\+\|f\|o\|u\|n\|d\| u:object_r:rootfs:s0
\|m\|e\|t\|a\|d\|a\|t\|a\| u:object_r:metadata_file:s0
\|m\|n\|t\| u:object_r:tmpfs:s0
\|o\|d\|m\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|u\|s\|r\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|f\|r\|a\|m\|e\|w\|o\|r\|k\| u:object_r:vendor_framework_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|o\|v\|e\|r\|l\|a\|y\| u:object_r:vendor_overlay_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|b\|i\|n\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|l\|i\|b\|6\|4\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|f\|i\|r\|m\|w\|a\|r\|e\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|e\|t\|c\| u:object_r:vendor_configs_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|l\|i\|b\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|a\|p\|p\| u:object_r:vendor_app_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|/\|p\|r\|i\|v\|-\|a\|p\|p\| u:object_r:vendor_app_file:s0
\|o\|d\|m\|_\|d\|l\|k\|m\| u:object_r:vendor_file:s0
```

using ls -Z outputs this `u:object_r:system_file:s0`

Why is this?
Thanks in advance.